# What is alternative solution to paypal pro due to PSD2 compliance issue

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions

After searching a bit it appears there’s no definitive solution for PSD2 compliance for CiviCRM as of now. We do not mind moving to a different payment processor. My only concern is which other payment processor that does onsite & back office card payment and handles recurring payments? Thanks

Comment: you saw this? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28071/paypal-psd2-new-european-union-directive-from-14th-september-2019?r=SearchResults&s=1|35.4541

Comment: Yes, I saw this but I could not find a definitive answer, hence looking for an alternative payment solution.

Comment: There is now a Make it Happen campaign for making the Stipe extension compliant: https://civicrm.org/make-it-happen/stripe-the-next-level